# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. (on both android and ios...running in expo)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I am trying to run the below code, but it throws the error "Text strings must be rendered within a `<Text>` component." I am using expo as of now. It reports no logs. The log section is empty.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
const [focusSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null);
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    focusSubject ? (
      <Text>Screen 1</Text>
    ) : (
      <Text>Screen 2</Text>
    )
  </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#252250',
},
});
```

Comment: Typo, `focusSubject ? (...) : (...)` should be in curly braces in JSX, i.e. `{focusSubject ? (...) : (...)}`. It's reading the input as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use conditions in `{}` .

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
const [focusSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null);
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {focusSubject ? (
      <Text>Where am I going to build a timer</Text>
    ) : (
      <Text />
    )}
  </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#252250',
},
});
```

Comment: Okay...got it.
Curly braces to access JS in JSX.